# Calling Inline Function in Macro Preprocessor of a C Program

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am confused by the following macro pre-processor definition:

```
#define HOOK_SYSCALL(NAME) original_##NAME = get_sys_call_table_addr()[__NR_##NAME];
```

The code for the function named get_sys_call_table_addr() is as follows:

```
ssize_t *sys_call_table = (ssize_t *)NULL;

void** get_sys_call_table_addr(void)
{
    void *swi_addr=(long *)0xffff0008;
    unsigned long offset=0;
    unsigned long *vector_swi_addr=0;

    offset=((*(long *)swi_addr)&0xfff)+8;
    vector_swi_addr=*(unsigned long *)(swi_addr+offset);

    while(vector_swi_addr++)
    {
        if(((*(unsigned long *)vector_swi_addr)& 0xfffff000)==0xe28f8000)
        {
            offset=((*(unsigned long *)vector_swi_addr)& 0xfff)+8;
            sys_call_table=(void *)vector_swi_addr+offset;
            break;
        }
    }
    return (void **) sys_call_table;
}
```

I'd like to ask whether this specific line:

> get_sys_call_table_addr()[__NR_##NAME];

is calling the inline function as an array? Like what we'd do to a normal kind of array, e.g. array[3];

Thanks!!

Comment: What does "call <function name> as a <type>" mean?

Comment: @immibis What do you mean? I don't really get it, sorry!

Comment: you said "is it calling the function as an array?", but that makes about as much sense as "is it driving the car as a fish?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`##` is used to concatenate preprocessor tokens. Suppose the `NAME` is `exit`. Then `get_sys_call_table_addr()[__NR_##NAME]` will be
`get_sys_call_table_addr()[__NR_exit]`. This means that `get_sys_call_table_addr()` is called and the evaluated result will be a pointer.

Remember that `arr[x]` is `*(arr + x)`. Let's say that `__NR_exit` is a constant with a value `1`. Then, the resultant pointer returned by the function is moved by `1` and then dereferenced. This will now be assigned to the variable `original_exit`.

Comment: I was thinking the same as your answer, just that I couldn't find any example explaining about inline functions called within macros definition, that's why I became unsure about it. Thanks for the answer!! =)

Answer (score 1):

the token ## is used to concatenate two tokens into one. For example in the above example __NR_##NAME becomes __NR_NAME.

The function get_sys_call_table_addr() returns a table sys_call_table, which is a double pointer. This table shall be used as a array variable and points to address pointed by [__NR_NAME].

In otherwords, get_sys_call_table_addr()[__NR_##NAME] becomes sys_call_table[__NR_NAME];

Comment: Thanks for answering, voted @Arjun Sreedharan answer because he answered earlier. Thanks for the clarification though =)